# How to speed up this python code (conditional in loop)?

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy

I try to find a way that does not use the if...else conditional in the loop so that speeds up the code, any idea?

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a1[i, j] == 0:
            b1[i, j] = 1
        else:
            b1[i, j] = a1 / np.sin(a1)
        if a2[i, j] == 0:
            b2[i, j] = 1
        else:
            b2[i, j] = a2 / np.sin(a2)
```

Comment: I don't think the if/else statements are the problem. You have a for loop within a for loop, which I would guess would be the more likely source of the problem.

Comment: Dealing with nested lists will likely to be slow, just saying.

Comment: There might be something in the logic to help a little but, but with two `for` loops you're stuck with `O(n^2)` no matter what.

Comment: I don't follow this code.  It looks like `a1` is an array, because you're indexing into it using `a1[i,j]`, but you then set `b1[i,j] = a1/np.sin(a1)`.  Am I missing something obvious, like usual?

Comment: @DSM: like is np refers to numpy?

Comment: I assumed `a1 / np.sin(a1)` should really be `a1[i,j] / np.sin(a1[i,j])`.

Comment: @LieRyan: no, like assigning a whole numpy array result to one index of another array.

Comment: @user2863620 Post your code that constructs `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, and `b2`.

Answer (score 8):

You are computing the reciprocal of the [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function.  So you could do:

```
b1 = 1.0 / np.sinc(a1/np.pi)
b2 = 1.0 / np.sinc(a2/np.pi)
```

The numpy sinc function is vectorized, so you don't need to write the loops.

Answer (score 1):

The `if()` statements are considered `O(1)` time operations , although a missed branch prediction may be costly if efficiency is of the essence (in which case, running for loops within Python code isn't the best choice).

Other than the possible missed branch predictions, the asymptotic time is, as @Keeler mentioned, `O(n^2)`. Optimizing the code inside the for loop may help with some constant factors within the Big-Oh notation though, which turns out to be pretty fruitful in practice.

An optimization you could do is follow @Warren 's advice and use `sinc()`

Comment: Python doesn't *do* branch prediction.

Comment: No, probably not. Why not leave that up to the CPU, which implements branch prediction in hardware?

Comment: @Keeler: it'll do that on the Python evaluation loop, which is interpreting the bytecode. Branch prediction will *not* help or hinder with the branches in the bytecode, as the CPU cannot see those.

Comment: Not that it matters here; by using vectorized numpy functions instead, you move the loops over the array indices into C code anyway.

Comment: @Keeler: Python VM didn't do much optimization, by the time one CPython opcode is processed,  there would've been hundreds of CPU opcodes executed with tens of branches in between that any benefits gained of that single branch prediction is pretty close to zero.

Comment: Of course they move over to C, that's part of why they're faster. :) @LieRyan Upvoted, I completely overlooked that when I wrote my comment!

Comment: Well I definitely learned something new! Thanks for the productive discussion everyone :)